# Going from fragment to activity with a button. Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to implent the next code in Android Studio and it does not work.
I want to pass from a Fragment (GalleryFragment) to an Activity (postropa) with a button.
I have linked the botton with the function (BotonPulsado) and I don't know what is wrong (In the design view).

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK2Kl.jpg)

Code:

```
import (...)

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    public void BotonPulsado(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), postropa.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post the code as an image, paste it as here **as text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `Button` variаble as a class field.

```
private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
Button button; <<-------
```

After that you need to define it in method `onCreateView()`

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

And set `onClickListener()` on this button to handle the call.
There you must call the method that starts the activity.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BotonPulsado();
        }
    });
```

Your final code:

```
import (...)

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    Button button;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        galleryViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        galleryViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BotonPulsado();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    public void BotonPulsado() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), postropa.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```